# Equivalence of categories: example

Tags: category-theory

I would like to prove that the  the category whose object class is the set of $K^n$ where $K$ is a field and the morphisms are the K-linear transformations is equivalent to the category of finite dimensional vector spaces whose morphisms are K-linear transformations.

Any hint to define a fully faithful and essentially surjective functor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the first category, $\textbf{Vect}_k$ the second one. Then the functor you are looking for is the obvious one
$$F:\mathcal{C}\longrightarrow\textbf{Vect}_k$$
given by seeing $\mathcal{C}$ as a subcategory.